# How to plot 2 animated graphics with x axis fixed in matplotlib with subplots?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, fft

The purpose of the program: I need to plot a signal graphic on the top and a spectrum graphic of this signal on the bottom, only the y data in both cases varies.

I generate a sine wave with a random noise on the input and plot it on the top, that's working perfecly.

The problem is when I try to plot the spectrum graph. It's not updating for some reason and I didn't understand very well the functioning of matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

dt = 0.01
Fs = 44000.0              # sample rate
timestep = 1.0/Fs         # sample spacing (1/sample rate)
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)  # t range
n = 256                   # size of the array data
w = 10000                 # frequency of the input

data = np.sin(2*np.pi*w*t)



def update(data):
    # update the curves with the incoming data
    line.set_ydata(data)
    #line2.set_ydata(magnitude)

    return line,

def generateData():
    # simulate new data coming in
    while True:
        nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
        r = np.exp(-t/0.05)
        cnse = np.convolve(nse, r)*dt
        cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
        data =  np.sin(2*np.pi*w*(t)) + cnse
        magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
        magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])
        yield data

fig = plt.figure()

# plot time graph axis
timeGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
timeGraph.set_ylim(-0.2, 0.2)
timeGraph.set_xlabel('Time')
timeGraph.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# plot frequency graph axis
freqGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
freqGraph.set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
freqGraph.set_ylabel('|Y(freq)|')

# get frequency range
n = len(data) # length of the signal
print(len(data))
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
freq = k/T # two sides frequency range
freq = freq[range(n//2)] # one side frequency range

# fft computing and normalization
magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])


line, = timeGraph.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(t)), 'b')
line2, = freqGraph.plot(freq, magnitude, 'g')


# animate the curves
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generateData,
                              interval=10, blit=True)

plt.show() # open window
```

Bonus: how do I initialize data and magnitude correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for both the time and frequency graph to update, you need to set the data from both to the respective plots in the `update` function. Of course you also need to provide this data in the generating function. So the generating function should `yield (data, magnitude)` and the updating function should accept this tuple as input.

It is also a good idea to set some limits for the frequency graph, `freqGraph.set_ylim([0, 0.006])` such that it will not stay empty.

I do not know what you mean by *how do i initialize data and magnitude correctly?*. I think they are initialized correctly in the sense that they are calculated for every frame including the very first one.

Here is a working code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

dt = 0.01
Fs = 44000.0              # sample rate
timestep = 1.0/Fs         # sample spacing (1/sample rate)
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)  # t range
n = 256                   # size of the array data
w = 10000                 # frequency of the input

data = np.sin(2*np.pi*w*t)



def update(data):
    # update the curves with the incoming data
    line.set_ydata(data[0])
    line2.set_ydata(data[1])
    return line, line2,

def generateData():
    # simulate new data coming in
    while True:
        nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
        r = np.exp(-t/0.05)
        cnse = np.convolve(nse, r)*dt
        cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
        data =  np.sin(2*np.pi*w*(t)) + cnse
        magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
        magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])
        yield (data, magnitude)

fig = plt.figure()

# plot time graph axis
timeGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
timeGraph.set_ylim(-0.2, 0.2)
timeGraph.set_xlabel('Time')
timeGraph.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# plot frequency graph axis
freqGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
freqGraph.set_ylim([0, 0.006])
freqGraph.set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
freqGraph.set_ylabel('|Y(freq)|')

# get frequency range
n = len(data) # length of the signal
print(len(data))
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
freq = k/T # two sides frequency range
freq = freq[range(n//2)] # one side frequency range

# fft computing and normalization
magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])


line, = timeGraph.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(t)),'b')
line2, = freqGraph.plot(freq, magnitude,'g')


# animate the curves
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generateData,
                              interval = 10, blit=True)

plt.show() # open window
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was a bit confused with how "matplotlib.animationFuncAnimation()" works.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? If so, you can accept it. If not or if you are waiting for further/better answers, you may update your question with refined requirements such that people would know what you are looking for.

Comment: Sry, I didnt know about that :D Accepted.